# 0001_initial migrations Wont Create

Tags: django, migration

So I'm new to django and recently tried to create some migrations for a project.
I created the project, created the application name, and set the application name in the Installed apps section in settings.

Whenever I run 'python manage.py makemigrations ' it gives me an output of:

'No changes detected in app'

Then when i run 'python manage.py migrate' it gives me:

Operations to perform:

Apply all migrations: (none)

Running migrations:

No migrations to apply.

There is a migrations folder within the application module, it just has an empty '**init**.py' file inside.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `python manage.py makemigrations <APP NAME>`

Comment: Hello mate, you have to create and edit your models.py to have changes and them make migrations

Comment: I got it to work, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings. Py then INSTALLED_APP and then add your app name, and then your project should run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you add another module in same app or change some content in modules and when you run `python manage.py migrate` it automatically creates a new 0001 init python file in the migration folder.

Follow my previous answer to resolve your init empty problem.